# Intersect X and Y axes at origin (0,0) using scatter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I have 2 matrices:

```
X = [-1 -4 5 6]  ;
Y = [3 20 300 2] ;    %   Always > 0
scatter(x,y,4^2)
```

Scatter by default is not forcing X and Y to cross at origin (0,0).  Is there a way to do it?  Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is no built-in function that can do this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-216M68/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-216M68).

If you don't want to use the very basic tool provided with the above link, there are some good solution on the File Exchange, [a simpler one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22956-axescenter) and [a more powerful one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30018), though the latter uses some undocumented functionality.

Comment: Thanks.  That first link worked for me.  I had seen it before but I wanted to check if there is another solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the x and y gridlines to pass through the origin (like in [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/85779) example), I don't think there is an easy way to do it (there's a discussion on a similar question [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/85779)). On the MATLAB file exchange, there is [oaxes](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30018-oaxes-central-axis-lines-through-an-origin) which seems to do what you want. You'll have to refer to its internal documentation.

An alternative is to manually set the x/y limits and plot some axes yourself:

```
%Set limits
xlim([-10 10]);
ylim([-300 300]);

hold on;
%Plot data
scatter(x, y);
%Plot axes
plot([0 0], [-300 300], 'k');
plot([-10 10], [0 0], 'k');
hold off;
```

but then this will just plot a black cross, no ticks/numbers etc.